# Convert Likert scale to pairwise?

Tags: survey, methodology

I want to find a way to convert the Likert scale to Pairwise (AHP/ANP) scale, because my questionnaire contains 30 criteria to compare, and making a pairwise questionnaire will contain (30*(30-1))/2 questions, which are very long to answer for the respondents.

Does anyone know how to deal with that? or any other method to weigh my criteria?

Comment: Hi @user40398, welcome to Cross Validated. Your question seems to be a little bit hard to understand the way it is written now. Could you make it a little bit clearer? Perhaps give an example, or more details? You can make the changes by clicking the "edit" button below your question.

Comment: Thank you for considering to this comment, I need to find a way to weight my criteria according to the survey by questionnaire. I have 30 criteria in my questionnaire, which are too many for using AHP method (Pairwise). Do you know how to find the weight of each criteria by doing a survey?

Answer (score 1):

One reason to convert ordinal Likert values to ratio scale values is if you plan to do any math functions after obtaining the responses. As an ordinal scale, Likert responses support mode and median calculations, but not +, -, X, or / functions, nor averaging, raising to powers, etc. This is because there is poor equality of ratios between the scores. In other words, the distance between 1 and 2 is not the same as between 4 and 5.

If you use a standard Likert 1-5 scale (1 being most important), the interval ratios between the ordinal levels look like this:

```
2/1 = 2
3/2 = 1.5
4/3 = 1.33
5/4 = 1.25
```

To convert the Likert scale to ratio scale, create a pair-wise comparison matrix using AHP, and calculate its eigenvector. I like to begin with monotonal values in the matrix unless there is a reason to do otherwise. The resulting eigenvalues will be from highest to lowest: 0.50, 0.260, 0.134, 0.068, 0.035.

Using this ratio scale 0.503-0.035 (0.503 being most important), the interval ratios between the levels are much closer, looking like this:

```
0.503/0.260 = 1.93
0.260/0.134 = 1.94
0.134/0.068 = 1.98
0.068/0.035 = 1.95
```

We use AHP exclusively in modern QFD, a method of new product development. This improves the accuracy and confidence in the results, which impact multi-million dollar investments.

Comment: Please don't add your email & website info to your posts. You can put that on your userpage; notice that your identicon, w/ a link to your userpage, is automatically added to your posts.

Comment: This approach will only be valid if the true values underlying the likert ratings are ratio in nature, or the converted values exactly match a nonlinear relationship you are trying to model.

Answer (score -2):

Regina Dittrich and Brian Francis and Reinhold Hatzinger and Walter Katzenbeisser:
*[A Paired Comparison Approach for the Analysis of Sets of Likert Scale Responses](http://smj.sagepub.com/content/7/1/3.abstract)*

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit more? How do these authors solve the OP's problem? Right now this is just a reference which is only of limited use without a bit of explanation.